# Inno Setup Compiler: How to auto start the default browser with given url?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to start my default browser (chrome) with a given url:

`http://localhost/folder`

by using the `inno setup compiler` for `windows`

after the installer finishes, i run the wamp manager

what do I have to write in the `run` section to achive this?

ps:

this `app` should install a wamp portable collection (apache web server, mysql, php, phpmyadmin)

when the installer finishes, it should start the `wamp manager`, wait for max `5 seconds`, and then it should open de `default browser` with a given `URL`

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define WM "Wamp Manager"
#define Exewampmanager "wampmanager.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{0BA2F7BC-1EFD-4BF5-A06B-28E003B02760}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\cow1
DefaultGroupName=My Program1
AllowNoIcons=yes
LicenseFile=D:\New Text Document.txt
InfoBeforeFile=D:\New Text Document.txt
InfoAfterFile=D:\New Text Document.txt
OutputDir=D:\inno
OutputBaseFilename=setup2
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\wamp\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#Exewampmanager}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(WM, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

after hours of research, this is what i have:

and this is not the best version, but this is what i want

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "cow1"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "my cow, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define WM "Wamp Manager"
#define Exewampmanager "wampmanager.exe"
#define Chrome "Chrome"
#define ExeChrome "chrome.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{0BA2F7BC-1EFD-4BF5-A06B-28E003B02760}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\cow1
DefaultGroupName=My Program1
AllowNoIcons=yes
LicenseFile=D:\New Text Document.txt
InfoBeforeFile=D:\New Text Document.txt
InfoAfterFile=D:\New Text Document.txt
OutputDir=D:\inno
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[code]
#IFDEF UNICODE
  #DEFINE AW "W"
#ELSE
  #DEFINE AW "A"
#ENDIF

const
  WAIT_TIMEOUT = $00000102;
  SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS = $00000040;

type
  TShellExecuteInfo = record
    cbSize: DWORD;
    fMask: Cardinal;
    Wnd: HWND;
    lpVerb: string;
    lpFile: string;
    lpParameters: string;
    lpDirectory: string;
    nShow: Integer;
    hInstApp: THandle;    
    lpIDList: DWORD;
    lpClass: string;
    hkeyClass: THandle;
    dwHotKey: DWORD;
    hMonitor: THandle;
    hProcess: THandle;
  end;

function ShellExecuteEx(var lpExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo): BOOL; 
  external 'ShellExecuteEx{#AW}@shell32.dll stdcall';
function WaitForSingleObject(hHandle: THandle; dwMilliseconds: DWORD): DWORD; 
  external 'WaitForSingleObject@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function TerminateProcess(hProcess: THandle; uExitCode: UINT): BOOL;
  external 'TerminateProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExecInfoBrowser: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    ExecInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
    ExecInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ExecInfo.Wnd := 0;
    ExecInfo.lpFile := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\{#Exewampmanager}';
    ExecInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE;
    if ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfo) then
      begin
        if WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, 7000) = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
          begin
               ExecInfoBrowser.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
               ExecInfoBrowser.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
               ExecInfoBrowser.Wnd := 0;
               ExecInfoBrowser.lpFile := 'http://localhost/cow';
               ExecInfoBrowser.nShow := SW_HIDE;
               ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfoBrowser);
          end;
      end;
  end;
end;

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

;[Files]
;Source: "C:\wamp\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

[Run]
;Filename: "{app}\{#Exewampmanager}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(WM, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost with that `wampmanager`. So your aim is except running that `wampmanager` (controlled by a check box on the final page) also navigating to the URL specified by `MyAppURL`, automatically, without any other check box when the wizard is finished or something ?

Comment: yes, after the installaer finishes, i want to start the wamp server and also start the default browser with a given localhost url

Comment: maybe like this: #define Chrome "Chrome"
#define ExeChrome "chrome.exe http://localhost/cow/"

Comment: No, no. What if the user doesn't have Chrome at all (or just installed in a different location than you presume) ? Default browser you can open just by using `shellexec` flag (in the `[Run]` section entry if you would use that URL in the `Filename` parameter). That would internally use shell execution with the default verb, which chooses the associated default application, in this case a default web browser. Yet another question. Do you want to run that wamp server AND open that site both only if that check box on the final page is checked ?

Comment: pls paste example with the execshell

Comment: Before I do, I need to know something. You know, you can have two entries to run after the wizard is finished, but you will have two *"Launch xxx"* check boxes on its final page. Is that what you want ? Don't you rather want to have just one check box (like *"Run wamp server"*), which, if will be checked run that wamp server application AND open that web site ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38965/discussion-between-ionut-flavius-pogacian-and-tlama)

Comment: ok, i am online now, in the room

Answer (score 6):

To load an URL at the end of the installation in the user's default browser, simply do this:

```
[Run]
Filename: http://whatever.com/something; Description: "Visit website"; Flags: postinstall shellexec
```

If you want it to be unticked by default, also add the `unchecked` flag.

Comment: OP wants to have a single *"launch"* check box, which will execute some sort of server launcher (as I got it starts some services and terminates), wait for its termination and if that launcher terminates in some limited time, it opens a web site. And that's what you can't do in `[Run]` section.