# Goes to a site when setup is closed / finished / uninstalled

Tags: inno-setup

[Inno Setup Compiler: How to auto start the default browser with given url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292796/inno-setup-compiler-how-to-auto-start-the-default-browser-with-given-url/19306074#19306074) is not what I am wanting for. How / what code in Inno Setup when I want my `setup.exe` that if it's closed / finished / uninstalled, it will go to a certain site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a web browser from a Pascal Script use a function like this:

```pascal
procedure OpenBrowser(Url: string);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('open', Url, '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;
```

To trigger it, when installer closes, you can use the [`CurStepChanged(ssDone)` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    OpenBrowser('https://www.example.com/');
  end;
end;
```

Similarly for an uninstaller, use the [`CurUninstallStepChanged(usDone)` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usDone then
  begin
    OpenBrowser('https://www.example.com/');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!