# How to use Inno Setup to run a command like steam://

Tags: protocols, inno-setup

I am trying to make my Inno Setup program to run this command `steam://`

This command is used to open Steam program via the windows RUN tool.

I press `WindowsKey+R` and type the command `steam://` and it opens the Steam program.

How can i make Inno Setup call this command?

I tried the following without success:

```
[Run]
Filename: "C:\Users\LUCAS\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Run.lnk"; Parameters: "steam://;
```

also tried that code bellow, and calling `AfterInstall: RunOtherInstaller;` on [Files] section, but it gives error on installation: `%1 is not a valid Win32 application`

```
[Code]
procedure RunOtherInstaller;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('C:\Users\LUCAS\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Run.lnk'), 'steam://', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
    ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
  then
    MsgBox('Error!!' + #13#10 +
      SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

This link is a little strange... It actually points to nowhere when i try to follow it, but it is what calls the windows RUN tool.

I know i could call the `Steam.exe` from the default folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe` but i am trying to avoid problems with users who not have Steam on default folder... So i am trying to use this method running this "External Protocol" (i dont know if this is the right name for it): `steam://`

Answer (score 0):

You can check registry for Steam location.
Part of my script for triggering installation:

```
[Code]
function SteamNotInstalled(): Boolean;
var 
Path: String;
ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Valve\Steam',
     'InstallPath', Path)) and (FileExists(Path + '\Steam.exe')) then begin
              ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('"' + Path + '\Steam.exe' + '"'), ' -install' + ExpandConstant(' "{src}"'),
              '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
              Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Or you can use [`shellexec`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_shellexec.htm) in [`[Run]` section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `steam://` URL as any other URL.

```pascal
procedure OpenUrl(Url: string);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('open', Url, '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;
```

Or use `postinstall` `[Run]` section entry:

```
[Run]
Filename: steam://xxx; Description: "Run game"; Flags: postinstall shellexec
```

---

See also

- [How to open a web site after uninstallation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31182324/850848)
- [Inno Setup Compiler: How to auto start the default browser with given url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19292796/850848)